# C++, Progam Detection

Tags: c++

I want to detect if a window/process is running, and if it does, to make the c++ program close.

Something like this:

```
    if (FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Fiddler"))) {
        ;
        std::exit

            ;
    }
```

It doesn't works for some reason.

Comment: Maybe because `std::exit` is a function, so you need to call it like `std::exit( 0 )`. If solving that compiler error does not answer your question, please specify "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

WHy do you have random semi-colons floating in space?

This code should look like:

```
if (FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Fiddler")) != NULL)
{
    std::exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Never before has someone had a more appropriate username: Not-A-Good-Coder.  Try *reading a book* on C++. even a basic intro book would help a lot.